# Need help in Sales Order for Custom Action button

Tags: acumatica

I have created a custom action menu item under Actions in Sales Order screen, when i click on the custom button it will create an invoice and opens the newly created invoice in new tab, the problem is when i click on custom button without saving the Sales Order document, the sales order is not showing the current order in its original tab. Please have a look at below code and let me know what is the mistake am doing here.

```
    public PXAction<SOOrder> MyAction;
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "MyAction", MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Select, MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Update)]
    [PXButton]
    public virtual IEnumerable myAction(PXAdapter adapter)
    {
        Base.Save.Press();

        PXLongOperation.StartOperation(Base, delegate ()
        {
            using (PXTransactionScope ts = new PXTransactionScope())
            {
                //my code
               // here am creating invoice and showing newly created invoice in new tab.
            }

        });
        return adapter.Get();
    }
```

Comment: In the example you are saving the Sales Order by calling Base.Save.Press() right? The problem occurs with or without Save.Press?

Comment: yes, am calling Base.Save.Press(). the problem occurs on both with and without Base.save,Press()

Comment: ok, if the problem occurs with and without saving, can we assume it's unrelated to the issue? I have difficulty understanding the sentence describing the issue: 'the sales order is not showing the current order in its original tab.'. What is an original tab as opposed to a non original tab? And why is it not showing in tab specifically? Does that mean the sales order screen display the current sales order in the form header but not in the tab content?

Comment: for example, am in tab 1 in which i created sales order and without saving i clicked on custom action, after click the invoice is created and that newly created invoice is opening in tab 2, now when i come back to tab 1 to see sales order, the screen is showing like to create new record, but not showing the one which i created.

Comment: First of all, it's a common pattern to Save before executing an action. When invoking CreateShipment from SalesOrder it calls Save action. I think I might get it now, you created a new tab in Sales Order that shows Invoice linked to that Sales Order. You also created a new action that creates Invoice from SalesOrder screen. When you invoke that action it redirects to the invoice screen, when you close the invoice screen the sales order screen hasn't refreshed the invoice tab. Is that it?

Comment: You also created a new action that creates Invoice from SalesOrder screen. When you invoke that action it redirects to the invoice screen -- up to here it is correct.
Actually i have not created new tab in sales order screen, the tab 1 and tab 2 i mentioned in last comment was browser tabs.

Comment: Make sure you save before the action so we can get that out of the way. The behavior you explain can occur if something sets Document.Current to null in SalesOrderEntry graph or if you never saved the sales order and you invoked the Cancel action of SalesOrderEntry graph. If you executed the code as is from your question I doubt it's going to misbehave. So you could comment things out until it's not reproducible. In the worst scenario you can probably set back Document.Current to the good value after creating the invoice but it would be better to find the root cause that clears the current DAC

Comment: Thank very much for inputs, i will look into it.

Comment: Just to make sure, you meant redirecting to a new tab not redirecting in the same tab right? And by going back to tab 1 you meant clicking on tab 1 header in the browser not clicking the back button of the browser right?

Comment: absolutely correct, what you said.